# how do i hide !mso in lower versions of outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2003

I am developing html for email templates and found that  `[if !mso]`
is not being hidden in lower versions of Outlook 2000 - 2003.

[image]

HTML:

```
<span class="enf-btn">
    <!--[if mso]>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="button_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" alias="SOTHYS">
                        <img src="http://image.newsletter.meadjohnson.asia/lib/fe911372776d007c70/m/2/redeem-now-btn.png" alt="" height="30" style="display: block; text-align:center;" >
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !mso]-->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button_table left" >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle">
                        <a href="#" alias="SOTHYS">
                            <img src="http://image.newsletter.meadjohnson.asia/lib/fe911372776d007c70/m/2/redeem-now-btn.png" alt="" height="30" style="display: block; text-align:center;" >
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <!--[endif]-->
</span>
```

---

Can anyone please shed some light on this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to hide content on Outlook, works on all versions.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
*content here*
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

This should hide everything from Outlook 2000 on:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)>
    {content}
<![endif]-->
```